# Where is the "Bremsstrahlung" before the annihilation of an electron and a positron?

Tags: antimatter, matter

When an electron and a positron meet, they [annihilate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron%E2%80%93positron_annihilation) each other, converting into two gamma rays. Unless all of them hit in a straight line (very unlikely), they should emit [Bremsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) before the collision, but I think this is not observed. Can someone explain why the Bremsstrahlung is missing?

Comment: Would be hard to measure against the background of Compton radiation from the annihilation gammas.

Comment: Any spectrometer should be able to distinguish the gamma rays from other radiation. Why should this be hard?

Comment: Because  of the overlap with the Compton continuum caused by the annihilation gammas.  At te same energy, spectroscopy cannot help you to distinguish these from a bremsstrahlung continuum.

Comment: Even if this is the case, the Bremsstrahlung should be emitted before the gamma rays are emitted. Thus it should be detectable.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking of the interaction in terms of Bremsstralung is equivalent to treating each particle as acting independently in an external field, but as the particle interact under the field of their partner a better point of view is to consider the system as (excited or even unbound) state of positronium.

That is the dynamics of the system is better understood in terms of the relaxation of excited atomic states. And indeed the atomic spectrum of positronium can be measured.

Comment: This is an interesting one. It would imply almost every annihilation is preceded by a Positronium. And the spectrum of this should be detectable. Do we actually see this?

Comment: @JohannesMariaFrank No. This is shown by the angular correlation of the gammas (ACAR). This is a way to measure electron momentum distributions in solids. For example the Fermi surface of metals.

Comment: @Pieter I appreciate your answers, but they miss the point. We are talking on effects BEFORE the annihilation and not after. Also I asked if we actually see the spectrum of the Positron, which is also referring to BEFORE the annihilation.
You also pull the compton continuum out of your hat, but this isn't even referenced in the standard wikipedia article. You are welcome to amend the article or be a little more verbose.

Comment: @dmckee Thank you for pointing me to the Positronium. But it only adds more questions to the question. What is happening before the annihilation. If we think in terms of relaxation we should see a spectrum. If we think in isolated particles we should see Bremsstrahlung. So before the gamma rays, there should be something. Just changing the vantage point does not change the facts. So do we see something before the annihilation and if not why?

Comment: @JohannesMariaFrank My understanding is that observing the Rydberg spectrum of positronium is a tricky measurement, but it has certainly been done. But you shouldn't think that there is some fixed set of decay steps that *must* occur before annihilation. The hydrogen-like wave-function is non-zero for zero separation in all s-states, which means that annihilation can occur for any value of $n$ or even for an un-bound pair.

Comment: The other issue you may be having is that you keep saying "before" as if this is an experimentally clear matter. The time-scale for these things is pretty short, so building an instrument that could show the time ordering is a major challenge. And I don't know if this has been done.

Comment: The gamma correlations give information about  what happened before annihilation, because momentum is conserved. And this shows that the positron momentum is small compared to the electron momenta in a solid. Unless the sample has a high porosity. Then there is oftem a perfect 180 degree correlation, indicating that this was decay from positronium.

Comment: @dmckee The average lifetime of a Positronium is 125 ps (pico). That we can measure nowadays down to as (atto) so this is not a problem. If the wave function allows for direct annihilation it also allows for something to happen before. And this must be detectable.

Comment: @Pieter There you bring up an interesting point. If the whole energy is in the gamma ray and momentum is conserved (that is what the experiments show) why is this so, because there should be happening something before. At least parts of the particles should form a Positronium.

Comment: *"we can measure nowadays down to as (atto)"* A few very carefully rigged situations can give you that kind of timing measurement (they compare multiple runs while scanning the parameters of a fast-pulsed laser). Collecting data from a segmented, ionizing-radiation detector with $0.1\,\mathrm{ns}$ precision is not impossible, but it is difficult and expensive. (Up until a few years ago getting $1\,\mathrm{ns}$ resolution was consider a good job and sufficient for almost every need, then an old collaborator of mine showed a use for $0.1\,\mathrm{ns}$ resolution and the world changed.)